# XMLHttpRequest in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a FireFox-Extension and want to load Data from Server. But when I try to initialize the XMLHttpRequest with:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

The error console says:

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

Do I have to include something or why the XMLTttpRequest is not recognized?

Comment: Is your code inside a JavaScript module? If so, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2F_XPCOM.C2.A0components

Comment: Hi Felix! I am using it in the main.js within a function. But when I do it your way the add-on builder says 'xpi file can not be copied' ...

Comment: Are you using the new addon SDK? If so, I have not worked with it yet, so I cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: Yes the online addon builder at https://builder.addons.mozilla.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Add-on SDK (that you are using indirectly via the Add-on Builder) provides a [`request` package](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) that is essentially a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`, you should use it. From what I understand, you aren't given direct `XMLHttpRequest` access to prevent issues if the add-on is uninstalled/disabled while a request is being performed.

Answer (score 4):

For using XMLHttpRequest constructor you should add the XPCOM component constructor:

```
const XMLHttpRequest  = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1", "nsIXMLHttpRequest");
```

and after:

```
// some code
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// some code
```

More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_.2F_XPCOM_components)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Wladimir's answer is useful for most of such cases. But there is one more case.

I've found tris page trying to solve the problem with this error under Firefox 16. Strange, but I've never saw this error under Firefox 15.

I've got this error in content script on ***some*** pages. The script was injected at the start:

```
contentScriptWhen : "start",
```

It looks like in some cases window object was not initialized correctly. So, I've just changed script loading from start to end. It was possible in my case. The problem has gone...

I don't know why it appears, but know solution and hope that it will be useful for someone.